# Vulkan copying image from swap chain

Tags: image, copy, buffer, vulkan

I am using the vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer function and getting a memory access violation and don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
VkBufferImageCopy region = {};
region.bufferOffset = 0;
region.bufferRowLength = width;
region.bufferImageHeight = height;
region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
region.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
region.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
region.imageOffset = { 0, 0, 0 };
region.imageExtent = {
    width,
    height,
    1
};

vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(m_drawCmdBuffers[i], m_swapChain.buffers[i].image,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, m_renderImage, 1, &region);
```

The swapchain images are created here in the initialization code:

```
// Get the swap chain images
images.resize(imageCount);
VK_CHECK_RESULT(fpGetSwapchainImagesKHR(device, swapChain, &imageCount, images.data()));

// Get the swap chain buffers containing the image and imageview
buffers.resize(imageCount);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
{
    VkImageViewCreateInfo colorAttachmentView = {};
    colorAttachmentView.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    colorAttachmentView.pNext = NULL;
    colorAttachmentView.format = colorFormat;
    colorAttachmentView.components = {
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R,
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G,
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B,
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A
    };
    colorAttachmentView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    colorAttachmentView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    colorAttachmentView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    colorAttachmentView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    colorAttachmentView.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    colorAttachmentView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    colorAttachmentView.flags = 0;

    buffers[i].image = images[i];

    colorAttachmentView.image = buffers[i].image;

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImageView(device, &colorAttachmentView, nullptr, &buffers[i].view));
}
```

And my buffer is similarly created here:

```
VkBufferCreateInfo createinfo = {};
createinfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
createinfo.size = width * height * 4 * sizeof(int8_t);
createinfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT;
createinfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

//create the image copy buffer
vkCreateBuffer(m_device, &createinfo, NULL, &m_renderImage);
```

I have tried different pixel formats and  different createinfo.usage settings but none help.

Comment: What is a "swap chain buffer"? That's not a concept defined by Vulkan.

Comment: These are objects that map to the swapchain images retrieved by the fpGetSwapchainImagesKHR() function.  If I am not getting the swap chain images correctly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::supportedUsageFlags` defines the limitations on the ways in which you can use the `VkImage`s created by the swap chain. The only one that is *guaranteed* to be supported is color attachment; all of the other, *including* transfer src, are optional.

Therefore, you should not assume that you can copy from a presentable image. If you find yourself with a need to do that, you must first query that value. If it does not allow copies, then you must render to your own image, which you copy from. You can render from that image into the presentable one when you intend to present it.

Comment: I took a look at my code and the vkCmdBeginRenderPass doesn't indicate a VkImage target option.  The renderpass object that is in the info doesn't have any target information as well.  This indicates that the images of the swap chain are the default target.  How do I render to an vkImage manually after my renderpass is done.  If you could please provide sample code or point me to a tutorial that does the same thing.

Comment: @AnthonyDaniels: Rule #3 about Vulkan: there *are no defaults*. You must specify *everything* about the system. In this case, the images used as attachments in a render pass instance are specified by the `VkFramebuffer` object you passed to `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`.